# How to detect faces from video frames in real time while recording video in a service in android?

Tags: android, service

I have created a service which records video when someone tries to make a failed attempt to unlock the phone.When the service is running and capturing the video it also capture video frames in real time and detect faces from these video frames.

The problem is when service is detecting faces from video,more than 150 frames are skipped as seen in log cat.

How to detect faces efficiently so that this much number of frames are not skipped?

Here is my code

```
public class Background_Recording extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,Camera.PreviewCallback {
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    public static int MAX_FACES = 5;
    boolean stopped = false;
    Timer t;
    Bitmap bitmaper;
    Handler handler;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bit_collect = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera = null;
    int camera_type = 1;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera = Camera.open(camera_type);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/unlock.mp4");
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
            t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    stopSelf();
                    stopped = true;
                }
            }, 8000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getting exception ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int flagID) {
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, flagID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        camera.lock();
        camera.release();
        windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
            YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), size.width, size.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 100, os);
            byte[] jpegByteArray = os.toByteArray();
            bitmaper = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteArray, 0, jpegByteArray.length);
            bit_collect.add(bitmaper);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processing(bitmaper);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no frames ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void processing(Bitmap final_byte) {
        if (final_byte != null) {
            int width = final_byte.getWidth();
            int height = final_byte.getHeight();
            FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(width, height, Background_Recording.MAX_FACES);
            FaceDetector.Face[] faces = new FaceDetector.Face[Background_Recording.MAX_FACES];
            int facesFound = detector.findFaces(final_byte, faces);
            if (facesFound > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "face found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                final_byte.recycle();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no face found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your face detection on the UI thread - since your `handler` is attached to the main thread's `Looper`. You should move all this to the background. Try the code below instead, and see my comments explaining my changes. It might not work 100%, but it should be pretty close.

```
//at the beginning of your class
private HandlerThread handlerThread;

//...
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int flagID) {
    //Create a new thread which will be used by the Handler to
    //process the image data and run frame deteciton
    handlerThread = new HandlerThread("faceDetectionThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    Handler handler = new Handler(looper); 
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, flagID);
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
    try {
        //This solution only processes the last frame.
        //It waits for 100ms, and if no more data is received,
        //it will start processing. Otherwise, the previous posted
        //Runnable will be cancelled and replaced with the new frame.
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                processing(data, camera);
            }
        }, 100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no frames ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void processing(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

    // Bitmap processing must be on a background thread!
    // Moved this from the onPreviewFrame method
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), size.width, size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 100, os);
    byte[] jpegByteArray = os.toByteArray();
    bitmaper = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteArray, 0, jpegByteArray.length);
        bit_collect.add(bitmaper);

    if (bitmaper != null) {
        int width = bitmaper.getWidth();
        int height = bitmaper.getHeight();
        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(width, height, Background_Recording.MAX_FACES);
        FaceDetector.Face[] faces = new FaceDetector.Face[Background_Recording.MAX_FACES];
        int facesFound = detector.findFaces(bitmaper, faces);
        if (facesFound > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "face found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            bitmaper.recycle();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no face found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

//...

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.reset();
    mediaRecorder.release();
    camera.lock();
    camera.release();
    windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);
    handlerThread.quit(); //Don't forget this!
}
```

Also, I guess face detection will be faster if you decrease `MAX_FACES` to `1`.

Comment: Glad to hear it! In that case also please upvote the answer.

Comment: Hey @SachinVashistha, Can you please explain it little bit more or share your example code?